# Using BeautifuSoup to separate the hrefs and the anchor text

Tags: python-3.x, beautifulsoup

I'm using Python3 with Beautiful Soup 4 to separate hrefs from the text itself. Like:

```
<a href="yoursite.com" class=sample-class">LINK</a>
```

I wanna (1) extract and print yoursite.com, and then get LINK.

If anyone could help me that would be great!

Answer (score 1):

Locate the `a` element by, say, class name; use *dictionary-like access* to attributes; [`.get_text()`](https://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/#get-text) to get the link text:

```
a = soup.find("a", class_="sample-class")  # or soup.select_one("a.sample-class")
print(a["href"])
print(a.get_text())
```

Comment: Hey Tried this:


soup = BeautifulSoup(response.content, "html.parser")
link = soup.find_all(a, {class-name})


but it doesn't work with

print(link["href"])
print(a.get_text())

says that "list indices must be integers or slices, not str"


ResultSet' object has no attribute 'get_text'

Comment: you aren't putting the quotation marks around the strings in the `soup.find_all()` line. Look how alecxe did it above. Also `soup.find_all` returns a list of everything it found, not just one entry, so you might want to iterate: `[print(entry['href']) for entry in link]`

Answer (score 0):

> A tag may have any number of attributes. The tag 
>   has an attribute “class” whose value is “boldest”. You can access a
>   tag’s attributes by treating the tag like a dictionary:

```
> tag['class']
> # u'boldest'
```

> A string corresponds to a bit of text within a tag. Beautiful Soup
>   uses the NavigableString class to contain these bits of text:

```
tag.string
# u'Extremely bold'
```

you can find this in [Beautiful Soup Documentation](https://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/#navigablestring)